# How to access the Response from a ClientResponseFilter in JAX-RS?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, httpresponse

I'm writing a [`ClientResponseFilter`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/client/package-summary.html) and it needs to indicate a failure in response processing in some occasions.

I'm going to throw [`ResponseProcessingException`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/client/ResponseProcessingException.html) because its documentation says it is an

> ...exception thrown indicate that response processing has failed (e.g. in a **filter chain** or ...).

But also, the same documentation states that

> The exception contains the nested Response instance for which the runtime response processing failed.

But my `ClientResponseFilter` has no access to the [`Response`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) instance. The [`filter`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientResponseFilter.html#filter-javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestContext-javax.ws.rs.client.ClientResponseContext-) method takes a [`ClientResponseContext`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientResponseContext.html) that gives us access to all interesting information about the response, but not to the `Response` instance itself.

How can I pass the `Response` instance while throwing `ResponseProcessingException` from a `ClientResponseFilter`?

Comment: What do you need from the `Response`?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha, as I said, I need the `Reponse` instance to pass it to the `ResponseProcessingException` constructor.